# winforms autocomplete format strings

Tags: c#, winforms

```
cities = result.Results.Entities.Cast<Address>().ToList();
foreach (Address address in cities)
{
    int spaces = (30 - address.City.Length);
     string s1 = address.City.Trim();
    for (int i = 0; i <= spaces; i++)
    {
        s1 += " ";
    }
    s1 += address.PostalCode;
    customCollection.Add(s1);
}
```

I want to concatenate two strings so that they are arranged in columns in a textbox autocompletecustomsource.

No matter what I do I can't get the city and the postal code to align in columns.

I want:

> ```
> New Bedlam    101010
> New York      102010
> ```

I get:

> ```
> New Bedlam      101010
> New York      102010
> ```

Tried a bunch of things, string.format, padright, nothing works.

Comment: Perhaps I am being obtuse but aren't:  `I want:         New Bedlam 101010 New York 102010

New Bedlam 101010 New York 102010` already in the format you want?

Comment: Have you tried using a fixed-width font like Courier New? Could be a cheap and easy way to do it.

Comment: no - the spaces are not correct.  I want the postal codes to start at the same column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `string.Format` with a left-justifying width specifier:

```
foreach (Address address in cities)
{
    string s1 = string.Format("{0,-30}{1}",address.City,address.PostalCode);
    customCollection.Add(s1);
}
```

Be aware that if your text box uses a variable-width font (like Arial) then the zip codes WON'T line up.  Use a fixed-width font like Consolas or Courier New to align properly.

Comment: You can't change the font in a textbox autocomplete dropdown, but this does give the correct number of chars per city...

Comment: hello sir, if you don't mind, can you please prove to me if this answer will fix the right-Aligned for `PostalCode`?

Comment: @spajce the format string I gave will left-align postal code since there's no width specifier.  If you want to right-align it use a positive width specifier for the second placeholder.

Comment: if so, the OP wants to _right-Aligned for PostalCode_. so this will not be the answer right?

Comment: @spajce I don't see where the postal code should be right-aligned.

Comment: @spajce they will be - along the left hand side.  It doesn't matter in the example since the numbers are all 5-digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code with String builder 
Always try to use StringBuilder for String concatenate operation you can append strings to it and do other operations here is more information

```
 cities = result.Results.Entities.Cast<Address>().ToList();
                    foreach (Address address in cities)
                    {
                        int spaces = (30 - address.City.Length);
                         Stringbuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
                         s1.append(address.City.Trim());
                        for (int i = 0; i <= spaces; i++)
                        {
                            s1.append(" ");
                        }
                        s1.append(address.PostalCode);
                        customCollection.Add(s1.ToString());
                    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: this does not change the spacing / alignment.